# How to test a web application for memory leaks?

Tags: php, testing, web-applications, memory-leaks, load-testing

How to test a web application for the memory leaks?
How much does it contribute to the overall performance of the site?
Please suggest any tool which can help us test the web application for memory leaks.

Comment: Which operating system and web server do you use?

Comment: What programming language was the application written in?

Comment: Most of the time we use LAMP (Linux, Apache, MySQL, PHP) but we also have applications on ROR / Mongrel.

Comment: Might want to make the title more similiar to the first line... unless you are worried there might be a web application in your memory leaks :)

Comment: Hi Chris,
Thanks for bringing it to my notice :)

Answer (score 1):

Which platform are you developing on?  This makes all of the difference in the world.  A webapp done in Django/Python is going to test a lot differently than an ASP.NET site.  You're better off searching for profiling tools based on the platform you're developing for.

Answer (score 0):

for php, you can use xdebug and kcachegrind.